# Firebase Functions docx to pdf

Tags: node.js, firebase, pdf, google-cloud-functions, docx

Im using Firebase Functions, and I need to convert a docx document generated in the cloud using Firestore data, to a pdf file to save it in the Firebase Storage.

The problem is that i cant find a good converter that works in the cloud. I found some that work with Node.js, but in the cloud doesnt work, like unoconv. This need LibreOffice and Python to run. Other like office2pdf or docx-to-pdf or word2pdf are using Libreoffice, unoconv or they connect to a web page to convert (where you have to be a member).

So the questions are:

1. Is there a way to convert a docx to pdf in the cloud using Firebase Functions?
2. Is there a way to use unoconv in the cloud?

Im using Javascript and Node.js for deploy.

Comment: Replay from Jen Parson:
At the moment, there is no way to do that. Its better to use App Engine or Compute Engine. Then you can use the Admin SDK for Python to access storage.
You could also route everything through drive (upload a docx and download a PDF), but that would be difficult to scale.